# Why does Excel create an extra series in dynamically created scatter plot with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening, I am trying to automate some data analysis and graph creation at work. The whole program is fairly big, but below you can find a snip of the part that is causing me issues.

I have a listbox where the user selects which parameters to incorporate into the chart. After this the "Create Graph" button places these parameters in new sheet as the column headers, then it it looks for the corresponding values in a "RAW DATA" Sheet. All these works so far and the correct values are under their corresponding header, the problem is when I go to create the actual graphs. I used the following code to loop through the items in the listbox and create the series to be plotted maintaining the X-values constant between all of them. For some reason, I get an extra series with the X values being plotted as both X-values and Y-values. Hence the 1:1 slope. X-values are elapsed time.

[image]

```
Dim i3 As Integer
Dim ChartSheet As Chart

Set ChartSheet = Charts.Add
ChartSheet.HasTitle = True
ChartSheet.ChartTitle.Text = s

With ChartSheet
            
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    
    For i3 = 1 To UserForm1.ListBox2.ListCount
    
    .SeriesCollection(i3 + 1).values = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Columns(i3 + 1)
    .SeriesCollection(i3 + 1).XValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Range("A:A")
    Next i3
    
End With

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
```

Comment: Whenever you create a chart it's a good idea to remove any series which might have been "auto-added" (eg. if you had some data selected when the chart was added) `Do While ChartSheet.SeriesCollection.Count > 0: ChartSheet.SeriesCollection(1).Delete: Loop`

Comment: This just a portion of the code. At the beginning I wipe everything. That being said, do you think adding that removal inside the loop would fix this issue? I am away from my computer...taking a break!

Comment: Where are you adding the series to the chart?  Right now you don't do anything with Series 1 - is that intentional?

Comment: The following lines are the ones that populate the series for the scatter plot through the loop. The first time the loop goes through it should use the 2nd column as the Y values. The second time, the Y-values are the 3rd column and so one until the 6th column. The X-values should stay the same at every loop, column A:A.
.SeriesCollection(i3 + 1).values = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Columns(i3 + 1)
    .SeriesCollection(i3 + 1).XValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).Range("A:A")

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to add code - it's not really readable in a comments.

Comment: Your loop starts at `SeriesCollection(2)` though - what about the first series?  I can see where you're setting X/Y values, but what determines how many series there are in the chart?

Answer (score 0):

This question was cross-posted in Quora, and answered there.

Note the use of a range variable restricted to the used range on the worksheet. The code runs substantially faster as a result. Also note the use of the .NewSeries statement, and passing data to the SeriesCollection (index starting at 1 rather than 2 as pointed out by Bryan A. Pena-Cruz) using the fully qualified address of the source cells.

```
Dim i3 As Integer
Dim ChartSheet As Chart
Dim s As String
Dim rg As Range
s = "Sheet1"

Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s).UsedRange   'Code runs a lot faster if you restrict the chart to the used range rather than entire columns

Set ChartSheet = Charts.Add
ChartSheet.HasTitle = True
ChartSheet.ChartTitle.Text = s

With ChartSheet
    
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    
    For i3 = 1 To UserForm1.ListBox2.ListCount
        
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i3).Values = "='" & s & "'!" & rg.Columns(i3 + 1).Address
        .SeriesCollection(i3).XValues = "='" & s & "'!" & rg.Columns(1).Address
    Next i3
    
End With

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
```

Comment: So it looks better, but there are 11 series created in total and not with matching names. Refer to image link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ascquzh0Htrgi8F1dXbvoGNJJZ5HKA